# java webservices call without a reply : axis2 call.invoke() to call.invokeOneWay

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I've a package making use of the following code:

SOAPEnvelope retMsg = (SOAPEnvelope) call.invoke(message.getSOAPEnvelope());

...this expects a reply message and hangs without one. I've been asked to adapt this to fireAndForget with no reply.

I'm having trouble finding how to do this and noticed the invokeOneWay() method however this does not accept a SOAPEnvelope. Can anyone advise if this is the right approach or whether I can adapt the normal invoke() method to ignore a reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok this was easier than I thought just hard to find.

call.setProperty(JMSConstants.WAIT_FOR_RESPONSE,
                false); //Defaults to true